# How to specify query MediaStore.Audio.Media in Android SDK?

Tags: android, listview, audio, sdk, mediastore

I have a ListView of a music albums that are on my SD. I want to make another list that displays the songs that are on the album, when i click it. How to I query MediaStore only for that certain album?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this may help you.....

Specify where clause with MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM =

cur = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            proj, whereclause, null, null);